# Qt 5.10 semi-transparent background on QMainWindow using stylesheet

Tags: c++, background, stylesheet, transparent, qt5.10

I would like to set my QMainWindow class semi-transparent background using QMainWindow::setStyleSheet method.
I do something like:

```
QMainWindow window;
window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
window.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128)");
window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
window.setFixedSize(800, 600);
window.show();
```

and I got fully transparent Window, which is pretty much nothing I can see.
and if I do it without

```
window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

I got fully red Window.

I found out, inheriting 'QMainWindow', overloading 'paintEvent()' and use 'QPainter->fillRect()' with QColor with alpha do what I want, but it's not using stylesheet.

Anyone can help doing this using 'setStyleSheet()' method? I've already found lots of posts and answers, but nothing helped me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like i found the solution by accident. Have to create QWidget, set is as central widget on QMainWindow and set stylesheet on the widget not main window. Works just fine.

```
QMainWindow window;
window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
window.setFixedSize(800, 600);

QWidget widget(&window);
widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128)");

window.setCentralWidget(&widget);
window.show();
```